# Merge 2 results from the same entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I merge 2 results from the same entity and sort by date ?

I've just this code at the moment :

```
    $conversations1 = $this->getDoctrine()
                            ->getManager()
                            ->getRepository('AcmeMessageBundle:Conversation')
                            ->getConversations($this->getUser()->getId(), $current);

    $conversations2 = $this->getDoctrine()
                            ->getManager()
                            ->getRepository('AcmeAdosMessageBundle:Conversation')
                            ->getConversationsInverse($this->getUser()->getId(),$current);
```

But if I merge conversations 1 and conservation 2 the dates won't sort correctly. Is there an easy way to merge and sort by date ?

I've any idea how to do that.

Edit my solution

```
$conversations1 = $this->getDoctrine()
                        ->getManager()
                        ->getRepository('AcmeMessageBundle:Conversation')
                        ->getMoreConversations($this->getUser()->getId(), $current, $conversation->getDate()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$conversations2 = $this->getDoctrine()
                        ->getManager()
                        ->getRepository('AcmeMessageBundle:Conversation')
                        ->getMoreConversationsInverse($this->getUser()->getId(), $current, $conversation->getDate()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$conversations = array();
foreach (array_merge($conversations1, $conversations2) as $conversation) {
    $conversations[$conversation->getDate()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')] = $conversation;
}

krsort($conversations);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "merge"? Do you want to update the properties of one object with the properties of the other? Do you want an array of conversation objects? Something else?

Comment: No no, it's just for display a list of conversations. But for getting all conversations I must make two queries. Conversations need to be order by date. So if i juste make an array_merge(); that's not order by date. That's will be order like this : conversations1_30may, conversation1_25may, conversation2_28may, conversation2_22may. And i need to order like this : conversations1_30may, conversation2_28may, conversation1_25may, conversation2_22may. So I ask if there is a way in doctrine or if someone have a script for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **think** you can merge the 2 arrays into an `ArrayCollection` and then sort that (by way of making into a iterator and back again).

```
$merged = new ArrayCollection(
    array_merge(
        $conversations1, 
        $conversations2
    )
);

$iterator = $merged->getIterator();

$iterator->uasort(function ($a, $b) {
    return ($a->getDate() < $b->getDate()) ? -1 : 1;
});

$conversations = new ArrayCollection(iterator_to_array($iterator));
```

It's hardly the prettiest way of going about things but it might just work.

**Note** This was cobbled together from a bunch of different answers so I'm not sure of the quality of the actual results.

Comment: Thank you, I mix your solutions

Answer (score 1):

The best way to sort the conversations would be in the query itself by retrieving all your conversations in a single SQL statement (with a SORT BY option). Databases are extremely efficient at sorting results. If you can't actually do that in your repository code, for whatever reason, the iterator (posted above) is a clever solution. A simpler approach would be to construct a conversations array where the conversation date is the array index so the result can be sorted. So something like this as a basic example:

```
$conversations = array();
foreach (array_merge($conversations1, $conversations2) as $conversation) {
    $conversations[$conversation->getDate()] = $conversation;
}
sort($conversations);
```

This should yield a date sorted array of Conversation objects. Since doctrine returns an array of objects, you have to iterate through that list to construct your conversations array.

Comment: Thank you, I mix your solutions